# Multidimensional convergence in probability

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

If I have a vector $X^n=(X^n_1,...,X^n_m)$ is it true that $ \mathbb{P}(X^n\geq\epsilon)\rightarrow 0$ if $ \mathbb{P}(X^n_i\geq\epsilon_i)\rightarrow 0\ \forall i =1,...,m$ As $n\rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: Is $\epsilon$ a vector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\epsilon$ is a vector and that "$\ge$" must be considered component-wise.

$\mathbb{P}(X^n\ge\epsilon)=\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^m\{X^n_i\ge \epsilon_i\}\right)\le\min_{i=1}^m\mathbb{P}(X^n_i\ge \epsilon_i)$, so the *if* part is true.

It actually holds the stronger
$$\exists j\ \liminf_n \mathbb{P}(X^n_j\ge\epsilon_j)=0\Longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(X^n\ge\epsilon)\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow} 0$$

This also tells you that an eventual *only if* part needn't hold.